# Creating a Finite Group in Sage

Tags: abstract-algebra, sagemath

Create a finite group in $S_4$ in sage

$H=\{(),(1,2)(3,4),(1,3)(2,4),(1,4)(2,3) \}$

---

can make a cyclic group out of them with

S4 = SymmetricGroup(4)

v1=S4((id))

v2 = S4("(1,2)(3,4)")

v3 = S4("(1,3)(2,4)")

v4=S4("(1,4)(2,3)")

v2*v3

*can go one to find right or left cosets*

S4.cosets(H, side='right')

S4.cosets(H, side='left')

H.list() will list

make table

H.cayley_table()

*can find sing of elements of $S_4$*

sigma.sign()

***but cant make that group***

---

after commnets

Link  sage example its "not psude code"!!

https://cocalc.com/projects/63d635fd-6ae0-4732-afdb-6ef4f5103c5d/files/2017-10-18-083014.sagews

Comment: Could you make some effort to actually ask a question? You have written down an incomplete set $H$ which, so far, is not a subgroup. Then you've written down some random psuedo-code without any context.

Comment: its not psudo code

Comment: It's not executable code since you haven't instantiated $H$.

Comment: The whole point is that I cant make $H$ in sage that is my issue/ question. Ill try to share a sage page with  some cyclic group H

Comment: @user280095 If that is the point, then you should phrase that as a question. You didn't address David Hill's other point, which is that when you wrote a mathematical expression for $H$, you did not describe a *group*. Do you want the subgroup generated by those elements? Then you write $H = \langle \cdots\rangle$. There's a difference.

Comment: https://cocalc.com/projects/63d635fd-6ae0-4732-afdb-6ef4f5103c5d/files/2017-10-18-054753.sagews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your subgroup with the following code:

> S4=SymmetricGroup(4); H=S4.subgroup([S4("(1,2)(3,4)"),S4("(1,3)(2,4)"),S4("(1,4)(2,3)")])

The reason your code doesn't work is that you only defined a subset of $S_4,$ and sage got grumpy because it believes that objects have an associated "type."

Comment: The Cayley table should show up just fine now (it did on my end). The signature homomorphism works fine too.

Comment: thank you. you can do math and programming. You are a unicorn